# How to make use of SQL (Oracle) to count the size of a string?

Tags: sql, string, oracle, count

i was wondering if there was a function in Oracle to count the number of character size in Oracle, i.e. given "Burger", the SQL returns 6.

```
i.e. select XXX('Burger') from DUAL;
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can use [LENGTH()](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions076.htm) for CHAR / VARCHAR2 and [DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH()](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lob.htm#sthref3118) for CLOB. Both functions will count actual characters (not bytes).

See the linked documentation if you do need bytes.

Comment: I have, on occasion, seen systems that pad with blank spaces to make data in a column uniform length and had to use `LENGTH(TRIM())` to get actual value lengths.

Comment: @Wayne That's usually the case for `CHAR` columns - `CHAR` columns are always padded to the defined length, whereas `VARCHAR` columns aren't.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt I realize that but thought it might be helpful to some people since you don't need the white space when querying a `CHAR` and the data type is not always obvious without checking the schema.

Comment: What about `NCHAR` and `NVARCHAR2`?

Answer (score 22):

you need length() function

```
select length(customer_name) from ar.ra_customers
```

Answer (score 6):

The length function will do it.  See http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/length.php

Answer (score 3):

Regarding to Your example

```
select length('Burger') from dual;
```

I hope this will help :)